# Entity Framework Core exception: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Song'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have these model classes:

**Song**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DataLayer.Entities
{
    public class Song
    {
        public int SongId { get; set; }
        public string SongTitle { get; set; }
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }

        public Song() { }

        public Song(int songId = -1, string song_Title = "", int albumId = -1)
        {
            SongTitle = song_Title;
            SongId = songId;
            AlbumId = albumId;
        }
    }
}
```

and **Album**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DataLayer.Entities
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public List<Song> SongList { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public Album() { }

        public Album(List<Song> songs, int albumId = -1, string title = "", string artist = "")
        {
            AlbumId = albumId;
            SongList = songs;
            Title = title;
            Artist = artist;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this **DbContext**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Domain;

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class ASContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Album { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Song> Song { get; set; }

        public ASContext(DbContextOptions<ASContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }

    public class EFDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ASContext>
    {
        public ASContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ASContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AlbumsSongsDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataLayer"));

            return new ASContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to add migration by running this command

```
Add-Migration Init1
```

but I get this error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Song'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'song_Title' in 'Song(int songId, string song_Title, int albumId)'

[image: error]

I don't know what to do, how to solve the problem? Help me please.

Comment: It seems you added song Title later to your class but had already a DBCreated?

Comment: Read about EF and constructors
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: EF will choose a parameter constructor if it sees one. But it cannot match the song_Title parameter to an entity property.   Maybe rename it to match the entity property SongTitle

Comment: The first thing I notice in the codes is about DbSet statements. I would use the plural of Song like public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }.

Comment: For me,When you add the default constructo `public Song(){}`,it will successfully migrate,please check it and migrate again.